# Retrieve exit status from php script inside of shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell, exit-code

I have a bash shell script that calls a few PHP scripts like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

php -f somescript.php

php -f anotherscript.php
```

I want to compose an error log and/or an activity report based on the results of those scripts.

Is there any way I can get the exit status of the php script in the shell script?

I could either use integer exit statuses or string messages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily catch the output using the *backtick* operator, and get the exit code of the **last command** by using *$?*:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=`php -f somescript.php`
exitcode=$?

anotheroutput=`php -f anotherscript.php`
anotherexitcode=$?
```

Answer (score 6):

Emilio's answer was good but I thought I could extend that a bit for others. You can use a script like this in cron if you like, and have it email you if there is an error.. YAY :D

```
#!/bin/sh

EMAIL="myemail@foo.com"
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin
export PATH

output=`php-cgi -f /www/Web/myscript.php myUrlParam=1`
#echo $output

if [ "$output" = "0" ]; then
   echo "Success :D"
fi
if [ "$output" = "1" ]; then
   echo "Failure D:"
   mailx -s "Script failed" $EMAIL <<!EOF
     This is an automated message. The script failed.

     Output was:
       $output
!EOF
fi
```

Using `php-cgi` as the command (instead of `php`) makes it easier to pass url parameters to the php script, and these can be accessed using the usual php code eg:

`$id = $_GET["myUrlParam"];`

Answer (score 4):

The `$output` parameter of the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command can be used to get the output of another PHP program:

callee.php

```
<?php
echo "my return string\n";
echo "another return value\n";
exit(20);
```

caller.php

```
<?php
exec("php callee.php", $output, $return_var);
print_r(array($output, $return_var));
```

Running caller.php will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => my return string
            [1] => another return value
        )

    [1] => 20
)
```

Note the `exit` status must be number in the range of 0-254. See [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) for more info on return status codes.

Comment: ahh thanks but is there any way to get the output when the php scripts are called from a bash script? That's what I meant to ask. I suppose I could rewrite the bash script in PHP to use the functionality you've described, which is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is more easy than the answer of Emilio:

Just execute the script

```
$ php -f script.php
```

and echo the exit code

```
$ echo $?
```

Comment: Seems pretty good. But if the php script says ‘echo 0’, then ‘echo $?’ prints 00. If 1, then 10.

Comment: yes, thats how echo'ing outputs to the console works in php. one can't prevent that