# abort build on php warnings/errors

Tags: php, bash, shell, jenkins, exit-code

We have several php scripts wrapped with other non-php commands in a single shell script, like this:

*build_stuff.sh*

```
mv things stuff
cp files folders
composer install
php bin/console some:command
php bin/console some:other:command
```

This shell script is then called in a "execute shell" build step.

```
sh ./build_stuff.sh
```

**Is there any possibility to abort the build as "failure", as soon as there are php errors/warnings?**

So that the next command wouldn't be executed.
And still maintain all commands in one script.

...

I found the Log Parser Plugin, but i would like to abort when the errors occur, not continue and parse the logs afterwards.

I though about maybe catching the PHP exit codes, as described here:
[Retrieve exit status from php script inside of shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647841/retrieve-exit-status-from-php-script-inside-of-shell-script)

But you wouldn't be able to *instantly* see text output of the php scripts then, would you?

Comment: Error codes can be returned to the shell.  Warnings will have to be overridden to be fatal to produce the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining them with double ampersands will do the job. In the below example `cmd2` will be executed only if `cmd1` succeeds (returns a zero exit status).

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

It will work with composer; but your commands might need modification to send proper exit codes.